# Poor battery performance after SSD install

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, battery, nvram

I recently installed a Crucial SSD into my Macbook Pro (2.66 GHz Intel Core i7), and now the performance of my battery is probably about 50% of what it used to be.

I've tried to reset the PRAM, but the OS loads so quickly that it I've never been able to trigger, even though I'm quick with hitting the keys.

Any suggestions for improving performance, and/or resetting the PRAM?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern Macintosh computers store very little information in PRAM so resetting it is seldom a useful troubleshooting step.

Have you checked the condition of the battery using System Information? (It's in the Utilities folder and also accessible from the menu: [Apple] > About this Mac > More Info… > System Report —assuming you're running Lion)

If you're seeing *Service Battery* under the Hardware > Power:Battery Information/Health Information section that's probably your issue.

[image: System Information]

You *might* improve the battery life with a [System Mangement Controller reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964). Assuming your MacBook Pro doesn't have a removable battery, the SMC reset procedure is:

> Shut down the computer. Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power
>   source, connecting it to the Mac if its not already connected. On the
>   built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and
>   the power button at the same time. Release all the keys and the power
>   button at the same time. Press the power button to turn on the
>   computer.   Note: The LED on the MagSafe power adapter may change
>   states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.

Comment: Not only is that not a healthy battery, it only has 57 cycles on it so it's probably defective. If the computer were under warranty Apple would replace it for free.

Comment: You might call up the vendor and see if they could ship you a second drive (perhaps a used one / return / loaner) just to rule out a bad drive? All but the most recent SSD generally use more energy than spinning drives in normal use - might yours be drawing more current by design than the older HDD?

Comment: @Richard That's **my** battery. My MacBook Pro is plugged in to the wall all the time. Apple has replaced the battery three times, (twice out of warranty) and the last time the Apple Store manager specifically told me that that would be the last time. (No complaints, I  was prepared to buy a battery.) I use the iPad when I'm on the go, so I haven't bothered to replace this one.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of defective Sony batteries or, there REALLY is a problem with using these types of computers plugged in 100% of the time. In my last three MBPs I've only had two battery issues (stopped holding a charge with low cycle counts) and both were dealt with within AppleCare and the new batteries worked for the rest of the life of the computer. I do use my computers on battery power for part of every day and it may be that that helps. I figured it increased the cycle count and I'd be getting new batteries yearly but it hasn't worked that way in my experience.

Comment: I checked the battery health, and it says "Normal" - Cycle count is at 86.

Comment: Glad your battery is okay. Try the SMC reset, else I'd take it up with the SSD vendor.

Comment: Sidenote: I also replaced my drive with a SSD and experienced the same problem. Battery is normal, so I went and performed the SMC reset. That fixed the problem. So as far as I am concerned, this is the authoritative fix.

Answer (score 1):

Any electric device that has a rechargeable battery will face the same issue if you overcharge the device. If you overcharge, you'll short the life of the battery and if you leave it charged for too long it might cause a fire.

I recommend you charge any electric device that has rechargeable battery to 95-98% and unplug it. In general, rechargeable battery life will decrease but if overcharge, you help short the life faster. To avoid replacing the battery within a year or so, charge to 90-98% and unplug.

Also do not use your device or put it in a hot area. If your device becomes too hot put it away to cool it off. Heat decreases your device's battery life. If you want to charge the battery the whole time, you must remove the battery to avoid overcharge. However, most Apple laptops do not have removable battery so you're better off by unplugging it between 95-98%.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/12838/should-laptops-remain-plugged-in-when-their-battery-is-100-charged

Answer (score -1):

To reset PRAM you need to press and hold <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>optn/alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> right after pressing power button and wait till it restarts with startup chime.

This shortcut triggers PRAM reset during POST procedure. It doesn't matter how fast or slow your disk is because it happens before any disk activity at all. Try press the combination after you send system to reboot from booted state.